# Add claims to user through azure ad b2c using graph api

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a web application and am planning to move all the authentication to Azure AD b2c. 
I need to create user through Graph API and now i can create user through Graph API, i also need to add claims

When adding user or updating user, after further googling i found out, you need to add extension property, I tried adding extensions, but it seems to be not working for me. Any help will greatly appreciated.

I am using the sample provided by MSFT https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet . I can now create an extension with the below JSON

```
 {
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "kart.kala1@test.com"
    }
  ],
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "Joe Consumer",
  "mailNickname": "joec",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "P@$$word!",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",


  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": null,
  "facsimileTelephoneNumber": null,
  "givenName": "Joe",
  "mail": null,
  "mobile": null,
  "otherMails": [],
  "postalCode": "92130",
  "preferredLanguage": null,
  "state": "California",
  "streetAddress": null,
  "surname": "Consumer",
  "telephoneNumber": null,

  "extension_a550f811ccfe41f19e895f7931f7a28a_admin": "admin1"

}
```

Above ***extension_a550f811ccfe41f19e895f7931f7a28a_admin": "admin1"*** property worked for me to add extension, but i created a user thru sign-signin profile in azure portal and then added the details which    is got from  **"GET-USER"** of another user and re-used the name. What is the alpha numeric value? is it created run time or can it be resolved using any value from the user data ?. I will have two accounts stage and production and i cannot be resolving the value or changing it runtime.

Comment: Can you please post the code, https requests, errors you are getting. Your question as is does not provide nearly enough information so that anyone can help you out.

Comment: updated the details with code @Saca

Comment: Any updates for this issue ? or you need more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have the rep to comment so need to put it in answer form.

I am not entirely sure what the question is, but I have successfully used the Graph API to set/get the extension data (for example using the JSON attribute extension_a550f811ccfe41f19e895f7931f7a28a_admin).

I am not sure how you are getting the user info but it seems as though it might be by name, which may not be unique.

For getting/setting B2C user info you need to use the objectId of the user as it is guaranteed unique. This means you need to store that objectId in your database/storage for that user.

Comment: My question is what is a550f811ccfe41f19e895f7931f7a28a stands for ?, i doesnt  look like object id of the user

Comment: It appears to be the "appId" of the b2c-extension-app, the one with the warning about not modifying it. It is auto-added to B2C tenants on tenant creation.

If you use the B2CGraphClient sample to list the extension app it will appear there:

b2c Get-B2C-Application